# Rector Failed to create "/tmp/rector_cached_files/26": mkdir(): Permission denied

Tags: runtime-error, php-8.1, rector

**When I run the command:**

vendor/bin/rector process --dry-run

**I get the error:**

[ERROR] Failed to create "/tmp/rector_cached_files/26": mkdir(): Permission denied

Web server processes on this system currently run as the user.

If I run the script as root it runs fine. It needs to be run by user!

I have a domain that this code runs fine on. I created a new domain called https://rector.86it.us and loaded the very same config that is already working on another domain. I did the very same setup with composer multiple times only to get the very same error over and over.

The new domain is on the same server and the configs are identical. I run PHP-fpm and I even switched back and forth from php 7.4 to php 8.0 and then php 8.1

I am running Apache with PHP 8.1 (ea-php81) (PHP-FPM)

**My current rector.php config.**

```
<?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    
    use Rector\CodeQuality\Rector\Class_\InlineConstructorDefaultToPropertyRector;
    use Rector\Config\RectorConfig;
    use Rector\Set\ValueObject\SetList;
    use Rector\TypeDeclaration\Rector\Property\TypedPropertyFromStrictConstructorRector;
    use Rector\Set\ValueObject\LevelSetList;
    use Rector\Core\ValueObject\PhpVersion;
    
    return static function (RectorConfig $rectorConfig): void {
        
        $rectorConfig->skip([
            //__DIR__ . '/src/SingleFile.php',
            __DIR__ . '/assets',
            __DIR__ . '/blocks',
            __DIR__ . '/install',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Forums',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Advertising',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Arcade_Tweaks',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Blog_Submit',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Blog_Topics',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Blogs',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Blogs_Top',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Bookmarks',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Cemetery',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/cPanel_Login',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/CSS_Color_Chart',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/CSS_Reference',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Docs',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Donations',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/ECalendar',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Evo_UserBlock',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/FAQ',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Feedback',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/File_Repository',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Google-Site-Map',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Groups',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/HTML_Newsletter',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/HTML_to_PHP',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Image_Repository',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Link_Us',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Loan_Amortization',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Member_List',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/My_Forum_Topics',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Network',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Network_Advertising',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Network_Projects',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/NukeSentinel',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Private_Messages',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Profile',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Proof_Of_God',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Recommend_Us',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Reviews',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Search',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Shout_Box',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Spambot_Killer',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Statistics',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Surveys',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Titanium_SandBox',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Web_Links',
            __DIR__ . '/modules/Your_Account',
            
            
            __DIR__ . '/admin',
            //__DIR__ . '/includes',
            __DIR__ . '/themes',
            __DIR__ . '/dev_modules',
            __DIR__ . '/cgi-bin',
            __DIR__ . '/.well-known',
            __DIR__ . '/vendor',
            
            // or use fnmatch
            //__DIR__ . '/src/*/Tests/*',
        ]);
        
        $rectorConfig->paths([
            //__DIR__ . '/admin',
            //__DIR__ . '/images',
            //
            //__DIR__ . '/mainfile.php',
            //__DIR__ . '/index.php',
            //__DIR__ . '/includes/Facebook/FacebookApp.php',
            //__DIR__ . '/includes/classes/class.cache.php',
            //__DIR__ . '/modules/Blogs/comments.php',
            __DIR__ . '/includes/classes/class.identify.php',
            //__DIR__ . '/modules/Shout_Box/shout.php',
           //__DIR__ . '/modules/Your_Account/public/new_user1.php',
           //__DIR__ . '/modules/Forums/posting.php',
            //
        ]);
    
        // register a single rule
        $rectorConfig->rule(InlineConstructorDefaultToPropertyRector::class);
        
        $rectorConfig->phpVersion(PhpVersion::PHP_81);
         //define sets of rules
            $rectorConfig->sets([
                LevelSetList::UP_TO_PHP_81,
                SetList::CODE_QUALITY,
                
            ]);
    
    
    };
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

open **vendor/rector/rector/config.php**
goto line: **68**

find:

`$rectorConfig->cacheDirectory(\sys_get_temp_dir() . '/rector_cached_files');`

change to:

```
$rectorConfig->cacheDirectory(__DIR__ . '/rector_cached_files');
```

This will fix the problem, CHEERS!